# change from Webforms views to Razor views not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I updated my MVC Views from Webforms to Razor.

What I did is that I rewrite manually all the code in Razor and excluded the aspx from the project. So far so good.

Now something strange is happening when I run the web site. I still get the Webforms views even if I excluded them from the project and replaced them with Razor views.

I did add this to my Web config file :

```
 <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"
 type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup,
 System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
       <section name="host"
 type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection,
 System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
       <section name="pages"
 type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection,
 System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
     </sectionGroup>   </configSections>

   <system.web.webPages.razor>
     <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory,
 System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
     <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
       <namespaces>
         <add namespace="System.Web" />
         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
         <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
       </namespaces>
     </pages>   </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I added this block to my Web config from the views folder.
I also added a _ViewStart.cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think IIS pays any attention to `.csproj` files.  So if your `.aspx` files are still in the directory, it will find them, and `.aspx` has precedence over `.cshtml` files.  You'll have to delete them or move them.  (Or write your own ViewEngine, but I doubt that's worth it for this.)